# Why does the second for loop need +i?

Tags: javascript, loops

I understand all of this and how it works, except: why does the second for loop need "+i"? And why can't it be replaced with "+1"?

```
text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric
blah blah blah Eric blah blah Eric blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];

// Look for "E" in the text
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === "E") {
        // If we find it, add characters up to
        // the length of my name to the array
        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: because `myName.length+i` is the ending character location for `Eric` from the starting location character at `i` so that is where that loop should end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `j` loop is offset by `i`.

`i` runs from 0 to `text.length`, say, from 0 to 100.

Whenever an `"E"` is found `j` loops from `i` to `i + myName.length`, so for instance from 50 to 54.

You could also have `j` loop from 0 to `myName.length` and do `text[j + i]`.

---

Note that this code not actually look for `"Eric"`, it looks for an `"E"` and then records the next 4 characters. If your input string is `"EaEbEc foo"` your result would be `[ "EaEb", "EbEc", "Ec f" ]`

Comment: I didn't realize the second for loop's "stop counter" begins counting at position 0, I figured it would start counting where the "start counter" started counting! It all makes sense now!!! and doing `.push(text[j+i])` makes sense too. Very awesome this place is awesome, thank you all!!! I wish I could give you all check marks..

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it's doing + i is because the code is trying to push every occurance of Eric from the text to Hits, so it wants to count myname.length letters. This could also be accomplished with j starting at 0 and using `text[j + i]`

Answer (score 0):

i is equal to the current position inside of the text. For example

```
     v (i = 5 Starting from 0)
Blah Blah Blah
```

Or

```
          v (i = 6)
Blah Blah Eric Blah
```

So i+name.length is marks the end of the Word

```
          v->v (i=11 -> i+lenth=14)
Blah Blah Eric Blah
```

If you would take +1 you would get

```
 v<-------v (i=11 -> 1)
Blah Blah Eric Blah
```